# How to declare typescript types when executing a ts file on Heroku?

Tags: typescript, heroku, ts-node

I have a typescript file that I execute locally using `ts-node`:

```
"scripts": {
  "commands": "ts-node --files deploy-commands.ts",
},
```

When I run the command on the Heroku deployed app using the Heroku cli:

```
heroku run npm run commands
```

I get typescript errors:

```
ts-node --files deploy-commands.ts

/app/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:820
return new TSError(diagnosticText, diagnosticCodes);
               ^
TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript:
src/commands/picks.ts:3:26 - error TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module 'luxon'. '/app/node_modules/luxon/build/node/luxon.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
Try `npm i --save-dev @types/luxon` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'luxon';`

3 import { Settings } from 'luxon'
                               ~~~~~~~
at createTSError (/app/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:820:12)
```

My package.json includes the types in devDependencies (I know Heroku strips these out)

```
"devDependencies": {
  "@types/luxon": "^2.3.1",
},
```

So I added types/index.d.ts with:

```
declare module 'luxon'
```

But still get the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The immediate issue is that `@types/luxon` is declared as a dev dependency, but [Heroku strips `devDependencies` after building your application slug by default](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#package-installation). They aren't available at runtime.

You could [disable dev dependency pruning](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#skip-pruning) or move that dependency to your `dependencies`, but a better option is to just not run TypeScript at runtime.

Instead, compile it to JavaScript in your `build` script and then run the JavaScript, e.g. using something like:

```json
"scripts": {
  "build": "tsc",
  "commands": "node deploy-commands.js",
},
```